# Split a pipe so output goes to two separate commands

Tags: r, tidyr, magrittr

I am in the process of learning the tidyverse and am loving the flow the pipe operator offers. I was wondering, is it possible to split a pipe at all so that the output from one part of the pipe can go to two separate commands? I have done a little research on this and have seen nothing about this being possible. So that instead of doing something like this where you would have to save the first step.

```
iris_filter <- iris %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Length <= 5.8)

iris_filter %>% 
  summarise(n= n())

iris_filter %>% 
  arrange(Sepal.Length)
```

Could you instead have `filter` passed to two separate commands and continue down two distinct pipe paths? A little image to clarify what I am curious is possible. [image]

Comment: No. Also, unless you were just dumping outputs of both chains to the console, this does not sound like a good idea vis-a-vis the logic flow of the program (and by extension, its readability, which is really what the pipe operator is about). You could however, use the `.` operator to pipe the output of the preceding expression to multiple arguments in a function call, if that is needed.

Comment: Yes, I had considered that this would reduce readability and disrupt the natural logic flow, but regardless it seems like it could still be something useful in some cases. Especially if one wanted to assign the two outputs of the split pipe using `->`. I realize there are workarounds and kind of hacky ways to do this. For instance in a simple example I found that you could pipe into `list()` where each element of the list was was a continuation of the pipe. Not sure how extendible this would be. Was just wondering if there was an actual feature that implemented this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%T>%` operator from the `magrittr`-package seems to be what you are looking for.

However for that specific problem I would write a custom function which outputs the original data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

custom.function <- function(x) {
  summarise(x, n = n()) %>%
    print()

  return(x)
}

iris %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Length <= 5.8) %>%
  custom.function() %>%
  arrange(Sepal.Length)
#>    n
#> 1 80
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species
#> 1           4.3         3.0          1.1         0.1     setosa
#> 2           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 3           4.4         3.0          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 4           4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 5           4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3     setosa
#> 6           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3     setosa
#> 8           4.6         3.6          1.0         0.2     setosa
#> 9           4.6         3.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 10          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 11          4.7         3.2          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 12          4.8         3.4          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 13          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.1     setosa
#> 14          4.8         3.4          1.9         0.2     setosa
#> 15          4.8         3.1          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 16          4.8         3.0          1.4         0.3     setosa
#> 17          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 18          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
#> 19          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 20          4.9         3.6          1.4         0.1     setosa
#> 21          4.9         2.4          3.3         1.0 versicolor
#> 22          4.9         2.5          4.5         1.7  virginica
#> 23          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 24          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 25          5.0         3.0          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 26          5.0         3.4          1.6         0.4     setosa
#> 27          5.0         3.2          1.2         0.2     setosa
#> 28          5.0         3.5          1.3         0.3     setosa
#> 29          5.0         3.5          1.6         0.6     setosa
#> 30          5.0         3.3          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 31          5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0 versicolor
#> 32          5.0         2.3          3.3         1.0 versicolor
#> 33          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 34          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.3     setosa
#> 35          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3     setosa
#> 36          5.1         3.7          1.5         0.4     setosa
#> 37          5.1         3.3          1.7         0.5     setosa
#> 38          5.1         3.4          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 39          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4     setosa
#> 40          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2     setosa
#> 41          5.1         2.5          3.0         1.1 versicolor
#> 42          5.2         3.5          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 43          5.2         3.4          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 44          5.2         4.1          1.5         0.1     setosa
#> 45          5.2         2.7          3.9         1.4 versicolor
#> 46          5.3         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 47          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4     setosa
#> 48          5.4         3.7          1.5         0.2     setosa
#> 49          5.4         3.9          1.3         0.4     setosa
#> 50          5.4         3.4          1.7         0.2     setosa
#> 51          5.4         3.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
#> 52          5.4         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 53          5.5         4.2          1.4         0.2     setosa
#> 54          5.5         3.5          1.3         0.2     setosa
#> 55          5.5         2.3          4.0         1.3 versicolor
#> 56          5.5         2.4          3.8         1.1 versicolor
#> 57          5.5         2.4          3.7         1.0 versicolor
#> 58          5.5         2.5          4.0         1.3 versicolor
#> 59          5.5         2.6          4.4         1.2 versicolor
#> 60          5.6         2.9          3.6         1.3 versicolor
#> 61          5.6         3.0          4.5         1.5 versicolor
#> 62          5.6         2.5          3.9         1.1 versicolor
#> 63          5.6         3.0          4.1         1.3 versicolor
#> 64          5.6         2.7          4.2         1.3 versicolor
#> 65          5.6         2.8          4.9         2.0  virginica
#> 66          5.7         4.4          1.5         0.4     setosa
#> 67          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3     setosa
#> 68          5.7         2.8          4.5         1.3 versicolor
#> 69          5.7         2.6          3.5         1.0 versicolor
#> 70          5.7         3.0          4.2         1.2 versicolor
#> 71          5.7         2.9          4.2         1.3 versicolor
#> 72          5.7         2.8          4.1         1.3 versicolor
#> 73          5.7         2.5          5.0         2.0  virginica
#> 74          5.8         4.0          1.2         0.2     setosa
#> 75          5.8         2.7          4.1         1.0 versicolor
#> 76          5.8         2.7          3.9         1.2 versicolor
#> 77          5.8         2.6          4.0         1.2 versicolor
#> 78          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
#> 79          5.8         2.8          5.1         2.4  virginica
#> 80          5.8         2.7          5.1         1.9  virginica
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Since you mention using `%T>%` to solve the issue, could you illustrate its use?

Comment: There is a good example in the documentation: https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/tee.html That function seems to be useful if the first command is used for its side-effects.

Comment: Hmm...I had not thought of that. This seems like there might be a good solution to have I have in my mind using something like this. I was thinking that the ultimate goal would be to save the output from the end of each pipe. I'm going to play with this and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. One workaround is to save the intermediate values in the full dataframe, for example:

```
iris %>% 
  add_tally() %>%
  filter(Sepal.Length <= 5.8) %>%
  arrange(Sepal.Length)

   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species     n
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>   <int>
 1          4.3         3            1.1         0.1 setosa    150
 2          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa    150
 3          4.4         3            1.3         0.2 setosa    150
 4          4.4         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa    150
 5          4.5         2.3          1.3         0.3 setosa    150
```

Here you can use functions such as `add_tally()` or `add_count(group1, group2, ...)`, which are basically equivalents of more verbose `mutate(n = n())`, and `group_by(group1, group2, ..) %>% mutate(n = n())`.

You can always use the values stored for further calculations / charts then.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware that for the example I provided this would be the way to do it. I wasn't trying to solve that problem per se. I was just looking for general information about if there is a standard way of splitting a pipe like I described above. Like I described in my comment above, I have found kind of hacky ways of doing it, but was wondering if there was a method that actually implemented it.